# Implementing datalist and searching for alternatives

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datalist

I am trying to implement a `datalist` in ASP.NET MVC. Following is the code with which I am trying to do so:

```
<div class="clearfix" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <div class="FloatLf" style="width:120px">Contact Name :</div>
    <datalist id="custServiceContactsSelection" > </datalist>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetDropDownData(f) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Rentals/Base/GetContactsForFacility?selectedFacility=' + f,
            data: { facility: f },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                $.map(response, function (item) {

                    $('#custServiceContactsSelection').append($("<option     />").val(item.ContactName).text(item.ContactName));
                });
            },

            cache: false,
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (errorThrown.indexOf("Your session has timed out") != -1) {
                    location.href = "/Rentals/Base/Timeout";
                }
            }
        });
    }    
</script>
```

Somehow I cannot see even the UI for datalist, when I am running it. Then, I noticed a warning when I bring mouse over the  `<datalist`which says: `"Validation (XHTML 1.0 transitional): Element 'datalist' is not supported"`.

1. May I know why is `datalist` not supported?
2. Is anything wrong with my implementation that I am not able to view UI of datalist or is it just because it is not supported?
3. What alternative can be used for datalist?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the HTML to:

```
<div class="clearfix" style="margin-top:20px;">
<div class="FloatLf" style="width:120px">Contact Name :</div>
<input list="custServiceContactsSelection" />
<datalist id="custServiceContactsSelection" > </datalist>

</div>
```

And it started showing the UI!